# i Don't want firefox to give save and open option, i want it directly to save

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

[image]

i don't want firefox to give these 2 option open with and save i want it to save automatically, please suggest how to do it file extension is "PEM", i am completely stuck.

Comment: As written, this does not appear to be a programming question. If it is, please include a [MCVE] as to how you are causing the save to occur.  If it isn't, then this question is not on topic for stackoverflow: Questions about **general computing hardware and software are off-topic** for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).

Comment: Go to`about:preferences` then select `Save files to` - http://i.imgur.com/YNGixsy.png

Comment: I HAVE STE THE DOWNLOADER FOLDER STILL THE OPTION IS COMING LIKE THAT , MY FILE IS .pem FILE